# When trying to analyze GPU trace file android studio 2.2 shows "Failed to connect to graphics debugger."

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I have been trying to use the new GPU debugger shipped as Beta in Android Studio 2.2.2. Recording a trace file works just fine, but when opening the .gfxtrace file I just get the message "Failed to connect to graphics debugger". Adb seems to be connected "adb devices" shows me the phone enabled for USB debugging. I am using a Pixel Phone with Android 7.1. which is not rooted.

Is there maybe some developer option on the phone that has to be enabled additionally ?

Thank you in Advance,

Till

Comment: I set the developer option  "Profile GPU rendering" to "adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo", as described as a prerequisite [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics.html#byb). Still not working.

Comment: hmm, that actually did it for me on Nexus 9 running stock Android 7.1.1 with February 2017 security update. Just set "Profile GPU rendering" to "adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo", reload Android Studio, clean project, edit run config -> profiling -> Capture GPU commands -> uncheck -> apply -> enabled it again -> apply. Run project from here and captured ~ 10MB -> stop capture -> it just told me "The GPU debugger is currently in beta", but worked. Android Studio 2.2.3. I guess the most important was "Profile GPU rendering"->"adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo" setting.

Comment: P.S. my app is arm 32-bit and using OpenGL ES 2.0.